# What drains the battery more: A longliving Service that does not do much or a many shortlived IntentServices

Tags: android, android-location, intentservice, battery, android-backup-service

I am designing an application which will collect different data from a lot of sensors and store them in a db, continuously. Sensors that I am using are like Google Play's fused location provider and activity detection. (There is some UI as well, but the UI will barely be launched, so almost everything is happening in the background)

I got two different ways to do this:

## 1) Start a longliving Service

So I would start a long-living service (with the STICKY flag), that would run in the background. The service would just register for periodic location and activity updates and - in between the updates - just do nothing.

Pros: App is only initialized once

Cons: Service is running 24x7

## 2) Register PendingIntent and use shortlived IntentService

Now Google Play's Location provider support registration of PendingIntent instead of callback [see here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%2C%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest%2C%20android.app.PendingIntent) which is even recommended for background tasks.

Pros: The app can get 'shut down' between sensor events

Cons: Each IntentService might re-start the app if it was shut down inbetween, which probably has quite an overhead (initialize db, read shared prefs, initialize all classes, ...)

So my question is: **Is it still recommended to use many short lived IntentServices for this kind of app?** I haven't done any measurements yet, but I am worried, that each IntentService (and they will be launched quite often), re-starts my app, so that I end up spending more CPU time on initialization, etc. then just having a long-lived service lying dormant.

Anybody has experience with this?